# How to make a continuous delete statement in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, hierarchical-data

I made a hierarchical structure table(reply-type board) in Oracle.
However, the difference is that each value refers not directly to the board_num above, but to the number of the final value. When creating a deletion query under these conditions, how can I delete only own sub-values, including themselves? Below is my code.

```
select  rownum"RNUM", board_num"num", board_re_ref"ref", board_re_lev"lev",board_re_seq"seq"
from (
select *
from board
order by BOARD_RE_REF desc, BOARD_RE_SEQ asc
);
```

---

```
    RNUM       num        ref        lev        seq
  --------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
     1          6          6          0          0
     2          7          6          1          1
     3          1          1          0          0
     4          5          1          1          1
     5          3          1          1          2
     6          8          1          2          3
     7          2          1          1          4
     8          4          1          2          5
```

when i delete num1, delete 2,3,4,5,8
when i delete num2, delete 4
when i delete num3, delete 8
when i delete num6, delete7

and I have to do this with just one delete query.

Comment: I couldn't follow the logic. Please explain how deleting board_num=1, deletes 2,3,4,5,8. Please explain the logic in more detail and remove extra column not necessary for the question

Comment: @K4M 'Ref' is the column for the number of the original article and num 2,3,4,5,8 is the answer to article 1. The level of the original article is zero and the answer is one and two. The answer to number 2 is number 4. And number 3's answer is number 8. 'Seq' is the order for the ref when you look at the board.

Comment: It's not yet clear. Let's start with the simpler sample: "delete num2, delete 4". I understand that when you say "num2", it's the row with num=2. And "4" is the row with num=4. Please tell us how the answer to number 2 became number 4.

Comment: @Junjie Num2 is a comment for num1. Because num2's ref is 1. And num1 has 0 lev so it is a original post. Num4 is a comment for num2 cause num4's lev is 2 and it place under the num2 (seq just means what blog looks like) But the table does not have column that can use 'connect by prior statement' And that is the limitations of this problem. With no prior column, with just a delete query.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally understood your question. It's like a blog and comment section. When you delete the blog, all its comments should also be deleted. If you delete a comment, then replies to that comment should also be deleted.

This delete statement might be the one you need, based on your sample data:

```sql
delete board
where board_num in (
  select board_num
  from (
    select b2.*,
      lag(board_re_lev) over (order by board_re_ref desc, board_re_seq) prev_lev,
      lag(board_re_seq) over (order by board_re_ref desc, board_re_seq) prev_seq
    from (
      select b1.*
      from board b1
      where board_re_ref=(select board_re_ref from board where board_num=&num_del)
        and board_re_seq>=(select board_re_seq from board where board_num=&num_del)
        and (
          (board_re_lev=(select board_re_lev from board where board_num=&num_del) and board_num=&num_del)
          or (board_re_lev>(select board_re_lev from board where board_num=&num_del))
        )
    ) b2
  )
  where board_re_seq=nvl(prev_seq,board_re_seq-1)+1
);
```

This statement, however, does not support level 1 rows with 2 or more level 2 rows.

It should be easier if you restructure your table and add foreign key constraint that deletes the child records when the parent row is deleted.

Comment: What you understood was right. This was an Oracle implementation question with reply-type bulletins. The condition does not include a parent key column representing the previous post, instead only the ref column, which is the value for the top post. The table cannot be rewritten. In addition, you must clear both itself and its child replies with only one delete query statement, not a procedure or trigger. As you understand, lev = 0 is the original text, and lev = 1 is the answer to the original text, and lev = 2 is for the lev = 1. I was impressed by the delete statement using lad.